# How to select/copy only text characters from HXD?

Tags: hexadecimal

Suppose you want only the text characters from a file with a bunch of other stuff in there too. Is there anyway to select only the ASCII characters? The text view in HXD shows everything else too.

Answer (score 1):

If by "text", you mean UTF-8 characters, e.g. from Chr(32) through 128, you could import the text into an editor such as [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and use a regular expression (regex) in the search/replace dialog to replace characters outside the desired range with nothing. In Notepad++,

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to open the Search/Replace dialog
- Turn to the *Replace* tab.
- In the *Find what :* field, insert the following Regex:

  ```
  [^\x1F-\x7F]+
  ```
- Leave the *Replace with :* field empty.
- Select *Regular expression* search type
- Click *RTeplace All*.

[image: Notepad++ Find and Replace non-ASCII]

Note that this might take some time for large files, because the text must be "closed up" each time a character is deleted.

*Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889996/how-do-i-remove-all-non-ascii-characters-with-regex-and-notepad*